# Are there any theories that deny the continuum hypothesis that are used outside metamathematics?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, meta-math

ZFC is consistient with the negation of the continuum hypothesis. Do theories that deny the continuum hypothesis have any use outside of metamathematics at the moment?

For example, I know that theories that deny the axiom of choice enjoy use in constructive mathematics and category theory.

I know that one cool thing you can do with cardinality is easily prove that something without a given property exists by showing that the total number of things is more than the number of things with that property (irrational number, transcendent numbers, uncomputable numbers, although I think these examples where first proven via other methods). Adding more cardinal numbers would probably help with this.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648550/statement-that-is-provable-in-zfcch-yet-unprovable-in-zfc-lnot-ch/ and you should also read about forcing axioms (Martin's Axiom; PFA; etc.) and the consequences they bring to the world of analysis and real numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila PFA especially, since it outright implies $\neg$CH (unlike MA); and for some neat applications of PFA and its variants, see http://www.math.cornell.edu/~justin/Ftp/Raach_notes.pdf and http://www.math.toronto.edu/tall/publications/UsefulModelSlides.pdf.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, although I wanted to say MA with a large continuum. And while we're at it, the existence of a total extension of the Lebesgue measure (which implies the continuum is a real valued measurable, or above one) is another example.